# Simulate Google Maps doubleclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, maps

I've created a Google Maps map using vue-google-maps, when the user double clicks on the map it zooms in towards the mouse location.

I would like to turn this into a single mouse click, so when the user clicks somewhere on the map it automatically zooms in.

The best solution I could come up with is to listen for a click event and then simulate a mouse double click with `dblclick` but this doesn't work

```
$("#certificate-dashboard-map").click(function() { 
  $(this).dblclick(); 
});
```

How could I simulate a double mouse click that would trigger Google Maps ? Any other solutions would also be welcome ofcourse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there is a option to enable single click zoom in vue-google-maps, which can be enabled by adding `:zoom-on-click="true"` to the map component